# Autotext on Word 2011

Tags: microsoft-word

Is using autotext the only way to have a text autofill in another part of the document? I am looking to create a document that is similar to this one:

http://www.kidzmet.com/files/trivial_pursuit.pdf

As I type it in, it automatically inserts the text below. Is this possible on a Mac? or Are there other platforms that are needed? Part of my problem is also not knowing what keywords to search for.

Thank you!

Comment: making the document in Excel would be much more easier I think, there using formulas is more efficient then setting up all the references in Word.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Mate, and I don't mean to be picky, but I would like to know how to create the word document like the one in the link. It would be a valuable skill for me.